# Need token delimiter that doesn't conflict with PowerShell or RegEx special characters

Tags: powershell, tokenize, delimiter

I have written a PowerShell function that expands tokens quite nicely. Unfortunately, I used % as my token delimiter, and now I find that % is a special character in PowerShell v3 that is likely to conflict. I am thinking I might use ~ as my delimiter, but I wonder if there is a best practice here? Something that is sure to not conflict with either PowerShell or RegEx, and since my users are not always IT folks, and only need to use my tool a few weeks out of the year, something that is really obvious would be helpful. 
I am currently expanding tokens before I do any other RegEx processing, and before I do any $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString(), but I keep finding new opportunities to expand the tool and I may be doing those things earlier at some point, so I want to future proof the data as much as possible.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!
Gordon

Comment: Can you post some code samples illustrating how you're using it and explain what kinds of conflicts you're encountering? `%` is not a special character for either regex or PowerShell interpolated strings. Note that if you're concerned about special characters in strings that you're using in regex patterns, you can escape them with **[regex]::escape()**, which you'd interpolate into a regex pattern like this: `-match "<regex stuff>$([regex]::escape($StringWithSpecialCharacters))<more regex stuff>"`

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what might be in the tokens.

Comment: %Location_Root%\ADSK\2015\RVT_2015\Seeds\UserDataCache\*.*

Comment: Wow, really, only 5 minutes to edit? OK. Heres the whole thing. Will  compose off line next time.

On the example front, this is what a string might look like:
%Location_Root%\ADSK\2015\RVT_2015\Seeds\UserDataCache\*.*
The token is then replaced with data from a lookup table based on the actual location, resulting in
\\BERLIN_SERVER\Rollouts\ADSK\2015\RVT_2015\Seeds\UserDataCache\*.*
As for conflicts, this (http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html) talks about % being used to initiate a verbatim argument, and while I don't foresee a conflict now, I know my karma and what happens if I ignore it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about using # as your delimiter?

It's not used at all in regex.  In Powershell is designates a comment, but only if it appears outside the context of a quoted string literal. In this application you're using it as a string delimiter, so it's always going to be used in a quoted string argument.

Comment: I had though about it, but decided against it for 2 reasons. 
One is conflating it with remarks, even though my users will only ever see XML which uses a different remark tag.
The bigger issue is that I am using this token expansion on strings that could reasonable have a # as part of the string. My RegEx expression only looks for pairs, but it could still cause all sorts of grief, and confusion when users look at their work again a year later. To some extent that argues more strongly for ~, as there is basically no chance of that in a user string. So, assuming that ~ is "safe" I may refactor.

Comment: If it could appear in the token content, that disallows it right there.